# Short story, possibly a Bradbury one: aliens visit Earth to see if we will destroy ourselves after we discover atomic energy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ray-bradbury

I am convinced this is by Ray Bradbury, but can't find it.

I remember a short story where a family of aliens are coming to watch the Earth and see if we destroy ourselves after we discovery atomic energy. They do this on vacation for their entertainment and have done it before with other planets discovering nuclear energy.

Comment: There's a somewhat similar story by Asimov that's about aliens (not a family) who are observing Earth waiting for the human race to destroy itself after discovering atomic weapons. Don't remember them being "on vacation" though. The story is "The Gentle Vultures".

Comment: if we would replace atomic energy with just catastrophic evens and specifically with pandemic meteorites then it could become a 1946 story https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintage_Season by  Catherine L. Moore and Henry Kuttner, published under the joint pseudonym "Lawrence O'Donnell"